# How to get InputStream of an https, chunked Push Servlet?

Tags: android, servlets, ssl, https, chunked

I spend three days in find out how I can connect to an https chunked push servlet and get an inputstream.
The connection with `HttpsURLConnection` works and also with `HttpClient`
but in every programmed code, when I try to get the InputStream of this servlet, this line blocks! No error, no exception, nothing. The debugger only stops at this line and wait.

I know that there is no `Content-Length` in the Header of the servlet and I know that this was the reason why the method `getInputStream` of `URLConnection` blocks.

But now I have no other Idea. Is there anyone who can help me to get this `InputStream` from the servlet? All connections are fine with `HttpsURLConnection` and `HTTPClient` **only getting the InputStream Fails** and I don't know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solved! Epic Fail: befor i connect to the servlet to get the response i have to connect to another servlet to start the session, than save the cookie and go on. i Used HttpsURLConnection and it works quiet good... Fazit: Streaming works well on Android

Comment: Mirko - can you share the code snippet?  I am having the same problem in my Android code, but I don't see how starting another servlet helps the problem generically.  I am in search of an Epic Fix :)

Comment: Hey mobibob - the problem was, that there was another servlet i had to start first. The problem was only on the Serversite. Do you need to login or something first? You need a session at first, befor you can get the stream.